# Using terraform to backup a docker volume when the docker image changes

Tags: docker, terraform, backup, volume, recovery

Is there a way to take a backup of a docker volume attached to a docker image with terraform before we start the container with an updated image?

This way if we need to revert the update due to some sort of failure we can attach the previous volume when we revert.

I have not found any blocks in the docker providers that allow for custom code execution before the container is started. Maybe I am missing something or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like your docker host is in EC2, correct? You could use terraform data life cycle manager to create snapshots of your docker host EBS Volume. With the launch template you can attach a volume from a snapshot. If you have terraform config started or anymore details, you should share.

Comment: Maybe `local-exec` provisioner can be used, I haven't tried it. And the `when` conidion would be set to `destroy`.